# Aws cloudfront - is it possible to make analytic for the traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Cloudfront is a CDN, so some of the requests from client are retrieved from cache.

I wonder if there is any method to count the traffic for Cloudfront by below criteria.

1.Record how many people access the website(in a day/week/month)?
2.Record the activity of using certain route(e.g. user Tim use POST /login in 2020-01-29 19:00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFront (CF) privides a rich portfolio of monitoring methods, some of them are:

- [CloudFront distribution metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/viewing-cloudfront-metrics.html#monitoring-console.distributions-additional)
- [Usage Reports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/usage-charts.html)
- [Access logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html)
- [Real-time logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/real-time-logs.html)
- and more

By going through these logs, I'm sure you can get the information you are after. It may be not so obvious at the beginning, but the log data should contain all its needed for that.

> Record how many people access the website(in a day/week/month)?

This I think you could check using `Requests` metric in `CloudFront distribution metrics` in CloudWatch.

> Record the activity of using certain route

This is more application specific. If there is no out-of-the box method for that, you could parse `access logs` to got such information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Amazon CloudFront console to display a graphical representation of statistics related to CloudFront edge locations. Please check the following [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cache-statistics.html)